# How to make plotly use my own downloaded world map?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, data-science, plotly-dash

I have a GeoDataFrame `eqs` describing earthquakes. I use the following code to display the earthquakes map (`tsunami` and `mag` are column in `eqs`):

```
fig = px.scatter_geo(eqs, color="tsunami", size="mag",
                     projection="natural earth")
```

The thing is, plotly use its own low resolution world map. So I downloaded high resolution world map from [naturalearthdata.com](http://www.naturalearthdata.com) and put in in GeoDataFrame `world`. I can't seem to make plotly not to use its own default map but to use my downloaded map instead.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible without additional libraries.

https://community.plotly.com/t/possible-to-use-custom-world-map-image-for-plotly-scattergeo/12986